# Get value of groups of radiobuttons in jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I wrote jQuery code to get all selected radio buttons in an `mvc5` view. However, it does not work properly. I want to save the selected radio button value in a database. How can I send the value of the button to an action?

```
         function f1() {
       var the_value;
      //the_value = jQuery('input:radio:checked').val();
      //the_value = jQuery('input[name=macro]:radio:checked').val();
      the_value = getChecklistItems();
     // alert(the_value);
  }
function getChecklistItems() {
  //  var columns = [];
    $('tr.cr').each(function () {
      //  columns.push($(this).('input:radio:checked').val());
       var the_value = jQuery('input:radio:checked').val();
       // var the_value = jQuery('input:radio:checked').attr('value');
        alert(the_value);
    });

   // return columns.join('|');
}
</script>
           <form action="~/Form/SaveFrm">

      <div>
     <div align="center">
        <table border="1" width="900" align="center">
            <tr align="center">
                <td></td>
                <td align="center">نام تیم میهمان</td>
                <td align="center">نام تیم میزبان</td>
                <td align="center">تاریخ انجام بازی</td>
                <td align="center">نتیجه بازی</td>
                <td align="center">نتیجه بازی</td>
                <td align="center">نتیجه بازی</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Item2)
            {
                <tr style="border-color:red" class="cr">
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="ID" value="@item.ID" /></td>
                    <td align="center"><label align="center">@item.host</label></td>
                    <td align="center"><label align="center">@item.gest</label></td>
                    <td align="center">@{
                        PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
                        <label align="center">
                            @p.GetDayOfMonth(item.datetime) / @p.GetMonth(item.datetime) /  @p.GetYear(item.datetime)
                        </label>
                    }</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="@item.ID" value="برد میزبان" />برد میزبان</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="@item.ID" value="برد میهمان" />برد میهمان</td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="radio" name="@item.ID" value="تساوی" />تساوی</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div align="center"><input type="submit" id="btn1" name="name" onclick="f1()" value="ذخیره پیش بینی" /></div>
```

Comment: You will need to provide more contextual information here. Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `:checked` radio button's value in an array like following using `map()` function.

```
var arr = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```